# PHP function to perform SQL query not working

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use a function to perform an SQL query and return the result. Doing a manual SQL query with the same query as the below works and returns the correct result but doing it within PHP is not working at all (page is blank).

**connection.php**

```
<?php

require_once("settings.php");

$conn = oci_connect($db_user, $db_pass, $db_ip.'/'.$db);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

require_once("connection.php");

function GetInvoice($n) 
   // returns invoice number for given order number
{ 
   $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = $n');

   oci_define_by_name($stid, 'InvoiceNo', $InvoiceNo);

   oci_execute($stid);

   echo "$InvoiceNo";
} 

GetInvoice(999645);

?>
```

Doing the manual SQL query shows a resulting `InvoiceNo`, it is just not working in PHP.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Any errors in the error log?

Comment: You are using variables that outside the function's scope. You need to pass `$conn` to your function. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a variable outside of function inside the function. That variable is not in function's scope. Due to this, `$conn` is undefined. Also, you have used `$InvoiceNo` withoud fetch result, I did some refoctoring on that place. You can use following;

```
function GetInvoice($n, $conn) 
   // returns invoice number for given order number
{ 
   $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = $n');

   oci_define_by_name($stid, 'InvoiceNo', $InvoiceNo);

   oci_execute($stid);

   while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
       echo "$InvoiceNo";
   }
}

GetInvoice(999645, $conn);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried that and I still see a blank page with no result shown. I tested the SQL query again manually a moment ago and it shows a result. Do you have any other ideas I can try?

Comment: @user2656114 Could you please put `error_reporting("E_ALL");` at the top of problematic page, so you can see error on page.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you are passing in functions, seems undefined

as you have created your function needs only one parameter, then from where this will get this variable `$InvoiceNo`

```
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'InvoiceNo', $InvoiceNo);
```